# Objects are not valid as a React Child - or How to Consume JSON in Function React?

Tags: json, reactjs, flask

There are a lot of threads that reference this same error; I've spent hours looking at them here and elsewhere but none I've seen have solved my problem.  If this is a duplicate of one I missed then thanks for showing me that. Otherwise, here goes.  I apologize in advance for the length of the post but I'm trying to include as much helpful information as possible.

I am consuming an API in Flask returning JSON.  The Flask API is:

```
@app.route('/api/getUsers')
#sample: http://localhost:5000/api/getUsers
def getUsersFromDB():
    return json.loads(userdata.GetUsers())
```

The API returns the proper JSON and the header shows the Content-Type is application/json.  The JSON is:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "emailaddress": "bobsmith@somedomain.com", 
      "firstname": "Bob", 
      "lastname": "Smith", 
      "userid": "bsmith"
    }, 
    {
      "emailaddress": "tomjones @otherdomain.com", 
      "firstname": "Tom", 
      "lastname": "Jones", 
      "userid": "tjones"
    }, 
    {
      "emailaddress": "carlinda@yahoo.com", 
      "firstname": "Carlinda", 
      "lastname": "Gonzalez", 
      "userid": "cgonz"
    }, 
    {
      "emailaddress": "athomas@freemail.com", 
      "firstname": "Thomas", 
      "lastname": "April", 
      "userid": "athom"
    }
  ]
}
```

The React app.js file is:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Users from './Components/AppUsers/Users';


function App() {
  const [UserList, setUserList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/getUsers').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
      setUserList(data.users);
    });
  }, [])   
  console.log(UserList)

return (<div>UserList</div>);  
//return (<div><Users userList={ UserList } /></ div>)
}

export default App;
```

The Users component is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import UserItem from './UserItem'

export class Users extends Component {
    
    
    render() {
        return (<p>{this.props.userList}</p>);
        /*
        return this.props.userList.map((user) => (
            <UserItem  user={user} />
        )); 
        */
    }
}

export default Users
```

Though the execution never gets here, here's the UserItem component for reference:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class UserItem extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<div>
                { this.props.user.emailaddress }<br />
                <p>{this.props.user.lastname}, {this.props.user.firstname}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const userDivStyle = {
    border: '1px #000 solid',
    width: '320px',
    height: '120px',
    margin: 'auto',
    textAlign: 'center'
}

export default UserItem
```

Output of the above app.js code is, pointing to app.js line 12 (`setUserList(data.users);`, is:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {emailaddress, firstname, lastname, userid}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

It is apparent that the API call was successful and that the JSON was parsed to get the user fields from ***users***.  If I change line 12 to `setUserList(data);` (*removing .users*) then I get this error:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {users}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

If I use the JSON as a string and assign it to the state using useState, it accepts the string as state but not as the JSON hierarchy it represents:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Users from './Components/AppUsers/Users';

function App() {

  const usersList = `{
    \"users\": [
      {
        \"emailaddress\": \"bobsmith@somedomain.com\", 
        \"firstname\": \"Bob\", 
        \"lastname\": \"Smith\", 
        \"userid\": \"bsmith\"
      }, 
      {
        \"emailaddress\": \"tomjones @otherdomain.com\", 
        \"firstname\": \"Tom\", 
        \"lastname\": \"Jones\", 
        \"userid\": \"tjones\"
      }, 
      {
        \"emailaddress\": \"carlinda@yahoo.com\", 
        \"firstname\": \"Carlinda\", 
        \"lastname\": \"Gonzalez\", 
        \"userid\": \"cgonz\"
      }, 
      {
        \"emailaddress\": \"athomas@freemail.com\", 
        \"firstname\": \"Thomas\", 
        \"lastname\": \"April\", 
        \"userid\": \"athom\"
      }
    ]
  }`;
  const [UserList, setUserList] = useState(usersList);

  console.log(UserList);
  /*return (<div><Users userList={ UserList } /></ div>);*/
  return (<p>userList</p>);
}

export default App;
```

Result from above, JSON input as a string rather than as an API call is:

> { "users": [ { "emailaddress": "bobsmith@somedomain.com", "firstname": "Bob", "lastname": "Smith", "userid": "bsmith" }, { "emailaddress": "tomjones @otherdomain.com", "firstname": "Tom", "lastname": "Jones", "userid": "tjones" }, { "emailaddress": "carlinda@yahoo.com", "firstname": "Carlinda", "lastname": "Gonzalez", "userid": "cgonz" }, { "emailaddress": "athomas@freemail.com", "firstname": "Thomas", "lastname": "April", "userid": "athom" } ] }

In app.js, if I uncomment the return using Users and comment the div that  just dumps UserList, I get this error trying to iterate UserList with map:

> TypeError: this.props.userList.map is not a function

The question is, how do I get app.js to accept the JSON output from the API and apply it to state in a way that the collection can be passed to Users component and, from there, the user item passed to UserItem?  I'm completely out of ideas to try.

Comment: seems like the code you have commented out should work? Have you tried that approach? 
In general, you need to convert your json into array by parsing and map over you react component.

Comment: Too much back and forth testing various code.  I corrected the first example app.js to show <p>{userList}</p> - it was missing the curly braces and  just printed the text userList.  This correction results in the error message in the first blockquote above.

Comment: Prãtéék Thápá, I assume you mean the commented-out code in app.js.  Either option for return yields the same error.  The error is generated in the call to setUserList in useEffect  and the code never gets to the return statement.

Comment: what data does the server return? Are you sure you're getting the correct data?

Comment: Two updates: Yes, I'm sure of the correct data from the server.  The quoted JSON above is copied directly from the results received from calling the API in Postman. Also, the error is not coming from setUserList as I suggested - too many variations that I've tried.  Currently, it's throwing the error on any use of UserList - so either return option has the error.  In the <p> case, the error is thrown in app.js because that's where UserList is used.  In the Users case, the error is thrown as soon as userList is accessed in Users component.

Comment: I got this to work.  I was back and forth so many times, trying various things, that I can't say what exactly it was that suddenly made it work but I think it was just a naming problem - making sure all variables are used properly.  Making sure that all the right names and capitalization on variable names passed is what did the trick.  Strangely, the error message was confusing because it was seeing the right data but it was the wrong data object.  For future readers - remember to double-check all of your names and objects passed from parent to child, etc.

Comment: good on you, mate